# Storing value of check boxes as 0 or 1 in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have four check boxes like this,

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="190px">
                <asp:ListItem>Programming Contests</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Seminars/Workshops</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Social Gatherings</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Tech Support</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I want to store the value of these check boxes as 0 or 1 in the table. Moreover, there may be a scenario when a user selects more than one check box, how to deal with that situation? I have used the 'bit' data type in the database. But the confusion I am having is how to store the **value** of these check boxes as 0 or 1 in database?

Comment: I dont really understand the problem here. Can you not make a bit value for each one?

Comment: in your db create a column with bit datatype to store 0 or 1

Comment: UI code and DB code are usually pretty far apart; all I can say is "treat it as a bool in c#, and a bit in TSQL" - but since you show no DB code, it is hard to comment further. For your second question: we'll, that is part of your design, yes?

Comment: how would you store multiple choice in a column that takes only 1 or 0?

Comment: @codingbiz. If he can have more than one then he needs to create a bit for each

Comment: @Josh and that will denormalize the table

Comment: Guys, I have edited the question a bit, I hope it clears everything.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the option increases or reduces

Comment: Well, I am trying right now to achieve my motive :P Let's see.

Comment: @codingbiz You have a good point about the growing options. I guess he could possibly create a linking table that can have multiple rows for each person. It will list the person and the option they desire and obviously the person can be in the table multiple times.

Comment: @unknownsatan If you ever think, you may add more options you may want to check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is quite simple. All you need to do is create a bit field for each option in your db. I do not see any other logical way of doing it.

The true or false value returned from your checkboxes are called bools in C#. Bools are stored in the database as bits translating true to 1 and false top 0.

**Edit**:

If you are planning on expanding the options, I would recommend something along the lines of the following. You can create a table that contains all the options and set a code for them. Then create a linking table that will include the person and the option they desire. If the user chooses multiple options, they will be put in the table multiple times (once for each option).

Comment: `I do not see any other` *logical* `way of doing it` :))

Comment: I have used bit but what about checkboxes? Like how to store their values in 0 or 1?

Comment: An alternative might be to use one `int` db column for the whole `checkboxlist`, where the int is actually a bit-mapped field for each `listitem` option. For example, checking the first option would be `1`. Checking the first and third would be `5` (1+4). This way you could logically represent the state of the `checkboxlist` in one variable, which may make sense since each option should be related (otherwise you would use `checkbox` controls and not a `checkboxlist`).

Comment: @Zhihao. That would take up more space though.

Comment: @JoshMein I agree, it most likely would. However this may be easier to work with or expand upon depending on OP's needs. Depending on the number of options, the OP could also use `smallint` or `tinyint`. Just an alternative to consider. :)

Comment: @Zhihao I have added another option to my answer. If the OP is planning on expaning the options, I guess it would be the option I would recommend the most.

Comment: @Zhihao what if I checked 2 and 3 (5) or 1 and 4 (5)

Comment: @codingbiz sorry if I wasn't clear with my explanation. What I meant was that each option could be one digit in a binary number. 1 would be `1`, 1+2 would be `3` (11 in binary), 1+2+3 would be `7` (111 in binary). You can then pull the value from the database and use the `int` to determine what options were checked using bitwise AND (`&`), and an enumerated data type. For example, `9` would mean options 1 and 4 were checked (1001 in binary). In the example from my past comment I used the first and third options to denote `5`. That would be 101 in binary, which is where the 1+4 came from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: Table "checkboxlist" with fields Id, Description to hold the checkbox list items. Then have your table with which item (s) the user selected: Table "Checkboxanswers" with the field "checkboxitemId" which is a foreign key to the id field of "checkboxlist" then add another bit field to indicate if it was selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<int> checkList = new List<int>();
  foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
  {
     if (item.Selected)
     {
        checkList.Add(1);
     }
     else
     {
        checkList.Add(0);
     }

     //Now you can use this list to pass it to Sql
  }
}
```